# How to retrieve the userid from userprincipalname in azure active directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

My client has synchronization set up between an on-premises Active Directory (AD) and Azure Active Directory (AAD).

I am able to retrieve user information from AAD using Microsoft Graph without a problem but, I specifically need to get the **AD UserID**, ie ({domain}/{userid}).

I tried calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/firstname.lastname@domain.com/$select=userId` but it did not work.

My questions are, is it possible? And in that case what is the actual attribute name? I have been looking around but haven´t been able to find a complete list of attributes.

**EDIT:**
After receiving one answer from Marilee I am including the C# code I have been using, ish. Both the calls do work for receiving user information from AAD, but not the **AD UserID**, ie ({domain}/{userid}) that I am looking for.

Attempt no 1

```
    var requestUri = GraphBaseUri + $"/v1.0/users/{upn}?$select=userId";

    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken), requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    dynamic responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content) as JObject;

    return responseObj.UserId; //NOT WORKING
```

Attempt no 2

```
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
        requestMessage
            .Headers
            .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));

    // Retrieve a user by userPrincipalName
    var user  = await graphClient
        .Users[upn]
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();

    return user.ObjectId; //NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is;

```
var requestUri = GraphBaseUri + $"/v1.0/users/{upn}?$select=onPremisesSamAccountName";

var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken), requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObj>(content);

return responseObj.OnPremisesSamAccountName;
```

Notice the select where we collect the **onPremisesSamAccountName**. Though, I haven´t found a comprehensive list of all attributes possible to retrieve which would have been nice.

Answer (score 2):

The attribute you're referring to is the objectID. From Graph API you can use UPN like you said:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

You can look up the user in a few different ways. From the `/users` endpoint you can either use their id (the GUID assigned to each account) or their userPrincipalName (their email alias for the default domain):

```cs
// Retrieve a user by id
var user  = await graphClient
    .Users["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

// Retrieve a user by userPrincipalName
var user  = await graphClient
    .Users["user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

If you're using either the Authorization Code or Implicit OAuth grants, you can also look up the user who authenticated via the `/me` endpoint:

```cs
var user = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

**From Powershell you can query Object IDs:**

```ps
$(Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq 'myuser@consoso.com'").ObjectId
```

Comment: Well, this did sound promising but I may not receive the ObjectId using C# which is actually what I need then.

Comment: You want to retrieve using C#? This can be done. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.mobile.server.authentication.azureactivedirectorycredentials.objectid?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: This is not a mobile app, it is code in an azure function. What I remember I am using Microsoft.Graph 1.21.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 1.19.0 to retrieve the ObjectId as my edit above. ObjectId property is not found in the user object.